# Skipped ec2 installation error:fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "boto required for this module"}

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, devops, boto

I installed boto. But when I run playbook it's skipped ec2 server creation and asking boto required.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-11-186 ~]$ cat playbook.yml
---
- hosts: localhost
  remote_user: ec2-user
  become: yes

  tasks:

   - name: Install Ec2 Using Ansible
     ec2:
       key_name: 09August22
       instance_type: t2.micro
       image: ami-074dc0a6f6c764218
       region: ap-south-1
       wait: yes
       group: default
       count: 1
       vpc_subnet_id: subnet-0a7cfaa417087f89a
       assign_public_ip: yes
       aws_access_key:******** *O6M6CUJNSVG

       aws_secret_key: d********TGC3Cgm2++q1j1SPw5EznWAYG5An+Q
```

I installed boto. But when I run playbook it's skipped ec2 server creation and asking boto required. Is there any suggestion for this

Comment: You need to make sure you installed it for the version of Python Ansible is using.

Comment: The easiest way to make sure/check boto (or actually any other needed lib on the target) is installed on the correct target host in the correct python version is to add a [`pip`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pip_module.html) task in your above playbook rather than installing it by hand